# Ordering a list in arbitrary way

Tags: r, list

Is there a way to order a list in arbitrary way? For example, using a vector to order the list:

```
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] 2

> b = c(3, 1, 2)
> magicfunction(a, b)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you just mean re-ordering?

```
##Create some dummy data
R> a = list(3)
R> a[[1]] = 1; a[[2]] = "B"; a[[3]] = 2
R> b = c(3, 1, 2)
```

Then just order using a numeric vector:

```
R> a[b]
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] "B"
```